# URL Globalization in asp.net core 5

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I am about to change my asp.net core Globalization by URL.

Just like Microsoft official site:
https://www.microsoft.com/zh-cn/ is for the Chinese version.
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/ is for the English version.

What I want to do is something different:
https://www.aaa.com/zh-hans/index.html is for the Chinese version.
https://www.aaa.com/en/index.html is for the English version.
As you see above, I need to add a .html suffix also.

I found some tutorials on google.

Here is my code:

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            
            services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");

            services.AddMvc().AddViewLocalization(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix,
                options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources").AddSessionStateTempDataProvider();
            
        }


public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
        {


            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.                
                //app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            var SupportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo> {
                new CultureInfo("en"),
                new CultureInfo("zh-Hans"),
new CultureInfo("zh-Hant")
};
            var options = new RequestLocalizationOptions
            {
                DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en"),
                SupportedCultures = SupportedCultures,
                SupportedUICultures = SupportedCultures,
            };
            app.UseRequestLocalization(options);
            var requestProvider = new RouteDataRequestCultureProvider();
            options.RequestCultureProviders.Insert(0, requestProvider);
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
                {
                    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(name: "default", pattern: "{culture}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}.html", defaults: new { culture = "en", controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
                });
        }
```

However, after the website ran, it reports an error:

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
AmbiguousMatchException: The request matched multiple endpoints. Matches:

Sample.Controllers.HomeController.Index (Sample)
Sample.Controllers.HomeController.Error (Sample)
Sample.Controllers.HomeController.Privacy (Sample)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DefaultEndpointSelector.ReportAmbiguity(CandidateState[] candidateState)
```

It seems that's because I added a .html suffix in `MapControllerRoute`.

I am not quite sure whether my code is right for most of the tutorial is for asp.net core 2 or even for asp.net core 1. Most of the code now not work in asp.net core 5 anymore.

What's wrong with my code? Thank you.

---

HomeController:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Sample.Models;

namespace Sample.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;

        public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public IActionResult Privacy()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
        public IActionResult Error()
        {
            return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've never seen such kinds of duplicate endpoints, usually the endpoints are duplicate when you have the same controller names & controller action names. Here the action names are different (Index, Error, Privacy). So it's confusing. Please share your tested URL, is there other kind of routing (e.g: attribute routing) involved in here?

Comment: It is a brand new project for the test, never with any attribute routing. What's more, I test it with "Start without debugging" before, and I test it with "Start debugging" just right now. It reports more about the error. I added to the end of my question. @KingKing

Comment: well, looks like you need to use `UseRouting`, try placing `app.UseRouting()` before `app.UseRequestLocalization`

Comment: @KingKing Now it won't throw the endpoint error while it will still throw the matched multiple endpoints error. I add the code of the controller to my question(which create by the visual studio and I did not modify it any).

Comment: that's strange, suppose you try the URL `/en/home/Index.html` the actions `Error` & `Privacy` should not be a candidate at all (so no multiple matches). I'm not so sure about how the new endpoint routing works.

Comment: @KingKing I have updated my project to one drive(https://1drv.ms/u/s!AtcqjirAlaGYi4xix6ag7ePJevihDQ?e=jR6NDP). Would you please help me to solve it. Thank you.

Comment: sorry that I could not conveniently run & debug .NET 5 in my environment, otherwise I could have tried reproducing it on my side. Actually the equivalent code (with that same template) works fine in `asp.net core 2.2`, no multiple matches found. Hope someone else will take a look at it.

Comment: @KingKing OK, thank you all the same.